# Remote SharePoint 2010 list add new item from SharePoint 2013

Tags: sharepoint-designer, jquery, jsom

I have a SharePoint 2010 list on a remote site. End users are using a different SharePoint 2013 site. Now they need an interface where they can add data to SharePoint 2010 list from SharePoint 2013 site. 
I have tried using JSOM but it didn't worked due to cross domain reference. Server side coding is not allowed on both the environments and even we can not make any changes to the web.config. 
Is there any option we can achieve this by using JSOM, designer workflows preferably ?

Answer (score 0):

You can try managed client object model.Create Visual Web Part using managed CSOM.

But if farm solution is not allowed in 2013 and JSOM is also not working then go for **custom REST api** or **Web api**.

Create and publish rest api with "**allow cross domain access**". Write required code (add/update list item in SharePoint 2010)in managed client object model.

And use this resp api in your JavaScript code in 2013 interface.

OR

**Create Provider hosted app with same code.**

Comment: How to create and publish rest api with "allow cross domain access" ? There would not be any server side code ? And how it can be hosted on a server, if server changes or hosting is not allowed ?

Comment: following is the link to create REST service.  http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/571813/A-Beginners-Tutorial-on-Creating-WCF-REST-Services

Comment: If hosting is not allowed on SharePoint server then you can ask for another server.IF another server is not available then ask for azure subscription.

Comment: There are very limited system resource available and we need to achieve it in the same available resources. Thanks for your time, I was looking for an out of box solution or through JQUERY/JSOM.